# How to make iPhone button stay pressed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

After the user touch the button I like it to stay pressed (highlighted).

I have tried to set the highlighted property in the touch-up event-handler, but it does not work. (I guess the the highlighted property is unset by apples code after my event-handler is called.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the "selected" state property instead.

```
- (IBAction)theButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.selected = !button.selected;
}
```

Comment: Okay +1, but it has no default visual effect on my button... What does "selected" mean? I thought it has something to do with input focus, but I might be wrong, can multiple GUI-elements be selected at the same time?

Comment: Yes, multiple items can be selected at the same time.

Comment: Note that you need to configure your UIButton's "selected" state first